# Getting error: Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style

Tags: windows, windows-8, uefi, mbr, gpt

I am trying to reinstall Windows 10 on my friends machine from bootable USB. Following is what I have done till now:

1. I created bootable USB using Windows 10 ISO and Rufus with `GPT Partition scheme for UEFI computer` option selected. Also I ensured that I formatted it with FAT32.
2. Machine was not detecting bootable USB drive. All it was showing in its boot menu is this:
   [image]

   So I enabled legacy mode:
   [image]
   and it started showing bootable USB drive in its boot menu:
   [image]
3. So I continued to installing Windows 10. However when selected partition in which Windows 8 was installed, it said `Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style`.

That means partition in which Windows 8 is installed is of type of GPT type. Also my bootable USB drive is of GPT type. Then, why it is not allowing to install?

Comment: Last time I had such issue file system was a problem. ISO contained 4GB+ file so NTFS was required, but USB UEFI boot usually works only from FAT32 (because manufacturers are lazy). So I just burned it to DVD (after initial failure when 4.7GB disc was too small for image ;)

Comment: I have created bootable USB with FAT32 only. Also from error, machine says target partition is GPT formatted (it is not complaining about the USB drive format). Somehow, it thinks it is requiring non GPT one. Am I right? Is it because I have enabled legacy mode and thus it is thinking that it should be expecting MBR USB drive and target partition?

Comment: Installation is booted in classic mode for some reason - GPT only works in UEFI. Try manually selecting boot option from boot menu (probably under F12), you might see same pendrive twice (classic and UEFI) - [should look somewhat like this](http://blog.tonywall.co/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/3-Force-UEFI-boot-of-Windows-setup-USB-from-BIOS-config-e1431854793632.jpg)

Comment: Added a screenshot of boot manager detecting the USB Pendrive in the question. F12 also brings in the same boot manager.

Comment: You can't install Windows in EFI mode if you enable Legacy mode.  Which also means you can't install Windows on a GPT partitioned disk

Comment: "Is it because I have enabled legacy mode" I don't have a specific solution, to tired to explain, but enabling Legacy mode is your current primary problem and is NOT a solution.  If the drive isn't showing up, it's a problem with the drive, not UEFI mode.

Comment: but the USB is getting detected in legacy mode. Actually I tried turning off Secure Boot, to check if USB gets detected in UEFI mode or not. It did not. So turned on Legacy Mode. Seems that I must try rebuilding bootable USB. Can you confirm `GPT Partition schema for UEFI computer` is correct option to select in Rufus?